# How to launch an html page using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, button

I want to make a button and when I click on it launch a html page. How can I do it?
Here is the incomplete example:

```
<button ng-model="status" ng-init="status=true" ng-click="status=!status">    
    <span ng-show="status == true" >Activo</span>
    <span ng-show="status == false">Desactivo</span>
</button>
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: ...So you want a link?

Comment: You might want to buy an `a` for your lunch ;-)

Comment: Jajajajaja!!! launch!!!! Jajajaja.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an simple 'a' tag to solve that:

```
<a href="somepage.html">Lunch somepage.html </a>
```

You can solve this using angularjs too, here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-model="status" ng-init="status=true" ng-click="myFunc()">
<span ng-show="status == true" >Activo</span>
    <span ng-show="status == false">Desactivo</span>
</button>


</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.myFunc = function(){
        $scope.status = !$scope.status;

        $window.location.href = '/somepage.html'; //this will redirect you to somepage.html
    }

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```